# jQuery, increase the height of a div to reach the bottom of the window

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV in my page, it's situated around the middle of the page. It's not the header...

I want to know how to use jQuery to set the height of the div so it goes all the way down to the end of the browser window.

Ideas?

So far I have:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    refreshWindowDimentions();
});
function refreshWindowDimentions() {
    // Height
    var newPreviewHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    $("#preview").css("height",newPreviewHeight);
}
```

But this fails as it doesn't know how to subtract from the current DIV's location.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#preview').offset()` to get the current position of the DIV. `offset().top` will give you the y coordinate of the DIV's top.

Also consider using `$(document).height()` instead of `document.documentElement.clientHeight` to save yourself the trouble of cross-browser issues.

Comment: Thanks. for some reason it's off my about 300 px? any idea why that is? Can something throw it off?

Comment: looks like $(document).height() was part of the problem. Any idea what's wrong with that?

Comment: @AnApprentice: Yes, padding and margins could affect the result, because they're not included in the height that you set, they're added afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what's wrong with the $(document).height()  suggestion?